# How to run multiple servers on Heroku?

Tags: java, heroku, cloud

I have a server installed in Heroku for my app, and now I want to install another Java-based server for my app for log purpose. How can I install a second server in Heroku?

Comment: Maybe look into worker processes, seems kinda heavy to have 2 apps for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is going to be a different kind of server, the best option would be to create another heroku application for it.

But maybe you don't need to roll your own server to handle logs? Heroku already saves logs for a short period of time. You can view these logs with `heroku logs` command. There are [addons](https://addons.heroku.com/) to collect these logs and persist them for a longer period.